# POST http://localhost:3000/api/customers 404 (Not Found) reactjs nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I pressed the submit button to upload data from ' tag' to the serverfrom the console came two messages

**Path**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzvnb.png)

**error message**

'Failed to load resource: the server rescheduled with a status of 404 (Not Found)

'Uncaght (in phantom) Error: Request with 404.'

**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const data = fs.readFileSync("./database.json");
const conf = JSON.parse(data);
const mysql = require("mysql");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host: conf.host,
 user: conf.user,
 password: conf.password,
 port: conf.port,
 database: conf.database
});

app.get("/api/customers", (req, res) => {
 connection.query("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER", (err, rows, fields) => {
   res.send(rows);
 });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

**App.js**

```
import Customer from "./components/Customer";
import CustomerAdd from "./components/CustomerAdd";
import "./App.css";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/Tablecell";
import CircularProgress from "@material-ui/core/CircularProgress";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    overflowX: "auto"
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 1080
  }
});

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { customers: "", completed: 0 };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(this.progress, 20);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.callApi()
        .then(res => this.setState({ customers: res }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, 1000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  callApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/api/customers");
    const body = await response.json();
    return body;
  };
  progress = () => {
    const { completed } = this.state;
    this.setState({ completed: completed >= 100 ? 0 : completed + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
          <Table className={classes.table}>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Number</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Image</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Birth</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Gender</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Job</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {this.state.customers ? (
                this.state.customers.map((c, index) => {
                  return (
                    <Customer
                      id={c.id}
                      key={index}
                      image={c.image}
                      name={c.name}
                      birthday={c.birthday}
                      gender={c.gender}
                      job={c.job}
                    />
                  );
                })
              ) : (
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell colSpan="6" align="center">
                    <CircularProgress
                      className={classes.progress}
                      variant="determinate"
                      value={this.state.completed}
                    />
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </Paper>
        <CustomerAdd />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

**CustomerAdd.js**

```
import { post } from "axios";

class CustomerAdd extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      file: null,
      userName: "",
      birthday: "",
      gender: "",
      job: "",
      fileName: ""
    };
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleFileChange = this.handleFileChange.bind(this);
    this.handleValueChange = this.handleValueChange.bind(this);
    this.addCustomer = this.addCustomer.bind(this);
  }

  handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.addCustomer().then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  }

  handleFileChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      file: e.target.files[0],
      fileName: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleValueChange(e) {
    let nextState = {};
    nextState[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(nextState);
  }

  addCustomer() {
    const url = "/api/customers";
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", this.state.file);
    formData.append("name", this.state.userName);
    formData.append("birthday", this.state.birthday);
    formData.append("gender", this.state.gender);
    formData.append("job", this.state.job);
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
      }
    };
    return post(url, formData, config);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
        <h1>고객추가</h1>
        프로필 이미지 :{" "}
        <input
          type="file"
          name="file"
          file={this.state.file}
          value={this.state.fileName}
          onChange={this.handleFileChange}
        />{" "}
        <br />
        이름 :{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          name="userName"
          value={this.state.userName}
          onChange={this.handleValueChange}
        />
        <br />
        생년월일 :{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          name="birthday"
          value={this.state.birthday}
          onChange={this.handleValueChange}
        />
        <br />
        성별 :{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          name="gender"
          value={this.state.gender}
          onChange={this.handleValueChange}
        />
        <br />
        직업 :{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          name="job"
          value={this.state.job}
          onChange={this.handleValueChange}
        />
        <br />
        <button type="submit">추가하기</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
export default CustomerAdd;
```

Comment: Are you sure that server is running on port `3000`?

Comment: no. Server is running at port 5000. 3000 ports operate on clients.

Comment: Got it, you had pointed to wrong port.

Comment: I set 5000 port as proxy address in package.json of client.  
          "proxy":"http://localhost:5000/"

Comment: R u still facing the problem??

Comment: I solved problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared route as get and making post request from axios. change it like following.

```
app.post("/api/customers", (req, res) => {
   connection.query("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER", (err, rows, fields) => {
   res.send(rows);
 });
});
```

Comment: I used get method to show db information in app.js and post method to update in form. I set up get only route in server.js, so get 404 error message, So I set 'route' on the post and it's solved.

Answer (score 2):

Which port is your node app running at? Judging from your code its 5000, and I'm guessing your client-side code is served on port 3000 by default. If that's the case, try replacing the path in `callApi` function to `http://localhost:5000/api/customers`